# DateTime.TryParseExact parses the month in my date incorrectly as January

Tags: c#, datetime

Below code snippet showing "07/01/2011" instead of "07/09/2011". Anything wrong with this code snippet?

Code Snippet:

```
DateTime result;
DateTime.TryParseExact(
   "07/09/2011", 
   "dd-mm-yyyy", 
   new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
   System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
   out result);

// shows "07/01/2011"
MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```

Answer (score 14):

`mm` is "Minutes". `MM` is month. Also, it shouldn't match anything, as in your date you're using `/` to separate the components and in the pattern you`re using dashes.

So either your date pattern should be `dd/MM/yyyy` or your date string should be like `07-09-2011`.

Answer (score 4):

The correct format string is `dd/MM/yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

`dd-mm-yyyy` should be `dd/MM/yyyy` because mm stands for minutes and `-` does not equal `/` in TryParseExact.

Check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx